# How to place origin at exactly the middle of highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How can I make always have the origin of the series start at the middle of the chart.  What I'd like is for 0 to always start at the middle of the chart regardless of the size of the chart or the values of the series. Currently highcharts control everything so if the series is from -10 to 10, this looks fine but if it's all positive values, 0 is at the very bottom.  I don't want to hardcode anything since the values are completely unpredictable.  Just center and the ability to scale unrestricted in the positive or negative direction

Comment: You could calculate the maximum or minimum value in your data set and then use that to set your `yAxis` max and min.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner) and calculate ticks.